# Appending to Informix BLOB without running out of memory

Tags: c#, database, blob, informix, chunking

I'm writing a c# app that inserts a large (1GB+) amount of data into a BLOB in an informix database.

However, many times the file is too large and the process runs out of memory.  I have implemented the WCF Chunking Channel to mitigate this, but I need to put these chunks into the BLOB without consuming memory to store them all.

How might I go about appending these chunks to the blob as they come in instead of buffering them all in memory first?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out, the IfxBlob classes Write method seems to write it directly to a LOB on the database server and seems to skip memory entirely, so there was no need for anything crafty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it translates to C#, but I think an ESQL/C solution is illustrated in the ESQL/C Reference Manual [Appendix C](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/sii-xc-10904b.htm) and the LO (large object) functions are listed in [Appendix B](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/esqlc09.htm), while [Chapter 8](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/sii-08-sourceforchaptitle.htm) describes how to use them all.

The Informix .NET Provider Guide (manual) has a section 'Type Reference' including a description of the [IfxBlob](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.netpr.doc/netpr031003254.htm#netpr031003254) class.

With luck, one or more of these should help you find the answers you need.